# Change placeholder depending by a condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple application with an input and a select in react js.
This is how the input looks.

```js
<input placeholder={myVariable === 'red' ? 'red':'blue'}/>
```

The select works fine and the input also. 
In my placeholder happens next: 
when user select `red`, `myVariable` becomes === red, and the placeholder should be  also `red` and so on. Now i have only 2 options, red and blue. 
**The issue**: when i select `red`, the placeholder is not changing, but if i select again `red` is changing, even when i put:

```js
 placeholder={console.log(myVariable)}
```

`myVariable` works fine, and is changing correct, but when i put

```js
<input placeholder={myVariable === 'red' ? 'red':'blue'}/>
```

the issue appears again.

**Question:**  what could be the problem? why when i use console log inside input, `myVariable` is changing, but when i use the condition, appears the issue?

Comment: The issue is outside of the code you show here. Looks like `myVariable` is not refreshing correctly

Comment: @Rashomon, but why if i use `placeholder={console.log(myVariable)}`, in console, `myVariable` is changing ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UseState` for this and just toggle the values between red and blue, [check out this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-2j7t8). It's hard to tell why your code is not working without seeing all of it.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";    

function Test() {
  const [place, setPlace] = useState("red");

  const getPlace = () => {
    if (place === "red") setPlace("blue");
    else setPlace("red");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <input placeholder={place} />
        <button onClick={() => getPlace()}>Change val</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Test />, rootElement);
```